# "image-min" is not working within "multer" in node js

Tags: node.js, image-processing, multer, imagemin

In node-js I am using `multer` package to upload the image. To compress the images I am using `image-min`.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var imagemin = require('image-min');

app.use(multer({
dest : './public/images/profiles/uploads/',
rename : function(fieldname, filename) {
    return (filename.split(" ").join("")) + Date.now();
},
onFileUploadStart : function(file) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
},
onFileUploadComplete : function(file) {

    var imagemin = new Imagemin().src(file.path).use(compressionType);
    imagemin.run(function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log('Files optimized successfully!');
    });
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
    done = true;
}
}));
```

when I run my code its throwing error.

> var imagemin = new Imagemin().src(file.path).use(compressionType);
>   ReferenceError: Imagemin is not defined

Comment: var Imagemin = require('imagemin'); at the top may be? Also, did you install Imagemin?

Comment: I have added the above line and installed image-min already

Answer (score 1):

```
var imagemin = require('image-min');
```

Should be:

```
var Imagemin = require('image-min');
```

Comment: This one fixed the error. But now it throws new error 

 var imagemin = new Imagemin().src(file.path).use(compressionType);
                                              TypeError: Object #<Transform> has no method 'src'